# SOAP session handling in CAMEL load balncer

Tags: apache, session, soap, load-balancing, apache-camel

How can I enable load balancing via SOAP sessions in apache camel.
I would like the request to be forwarded to the same server, to which the previous request was forwarded. My requests are SOAP with SOAP session enabled. Hence for each transaction a unique session id would be generated.
How can i forward the all the requests with the same session id to a single server?

Answer (score 0):

Look at stick load balancer:
http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html

You just need to specify an expression to identify the session tooken. Not really sure where such a SOAP session token is stored, but probably inside the SOAP XML request, so just find it via xpath.

from("whatever").loadBalance().sticky("xpath:/...").to(a,b,c,..);

Comment: thanks a ton for replying!! Well my SOAP session ID are specified in the ServiceGroupId in the SOAP header, as i use AXIS 2 to generate the session. And my SOAP header looks something like `<axis2:ServiceGroupId xmlns:axis2="http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2">urn:uuid:99A029EBBC70DBEB221347349722532</axis2:ServiceGroupId>` How would my expression look like?

Comment: when i use `.loadBalance().sticky(xpath("/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/wsa:ReplyTo/wsa:ReferenceParameters/axis2:Serv‌​iceGroupId/"))` I get an Invalid expression error! Any help please.

Comment: XPath expressions can be a bit cumbersome to get to work, specially with multiple name spaces. I think you should read docs and try your expressions out in a separate route first. http://camel.apache.org/xpath.html Mind name spaces, you need to include any prefix, like this: 
`Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("c", "http://acme.com/cheese");` 
`... xpath("/c:element",ns)`

Comment: What if I have more than one name space? As i cannot define more than one namesapce in `Namespaces` and I cannot use multiple namespace in `Xpath`

Comment: Yes, you can. It's in the same documentation page. Look at this source code http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor/XPathWithNamespaceBuilderFilterTest.java a bit down. Just call

`Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("foo","http://foo"); ns.add("bar",http://bar")`